# Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree a3’ with actual type ‘a’ ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for

Tags: haskell

I am running into this error of definition, not sure of why exactly.

**Definition:**

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [Tree a]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

**Function:**

```
count :: Tree a -> Integer
count (Leaf a) = 0
count (Node l r) = 1 + count l + count r
```

**Error:**

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree a2’
              with actual type ‘[Tree a]’
• In the first argument of ‘count’, namely ‘r’
  In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘count r’
  In the expression: 1 + count l + count r
• Relevant bindings include
    r :: [Tree a]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count :: Tree a -> Integer
count (Leaf a) = 0
count (Node l r) = 1 + count l + count r
```

Consider what would happen when evaluating this function on a simple test input.

```
-- | A small example tree:
--
-- > 1
-- > ├ 2
-- > └ 3
--
smallExample :: Tree Int
smallExample = Node 1 [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]
```

- `count smallExample` is `count (Node 1 [Leaf 2, Leaf 3])`.
- `Node 1 [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]` doesn’t match the first pattern `Leaf a`, so we skip the first clause.
- `Node 1 [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]` matches the second pattern `Node l r`, so we take the second clause.

  - `l` is `1` of type `Int`.
  - `r` is `[Leaf 2, Leaf 3]` of type `[Tree Int]`.
  - `1 + count l + count r` is `1 + count 1 + count [Leaf 2, Leaf 3]`.

Now there are two inconsistencies:

1. In `count l`, `Int` doesn’t match `Tree a`. This can be solved by removing `count l` from the summation altogether, because the `1` already represents counting the `Node`.
2. In `count r`, `[Tree a]` doesn’t match `Tree a`. This can be solved by using `map` to count all of the subtrees’ sizes, and `sum` to add them up.

   ```
   count (Node l r) = 1 + sum (map count r)
   ```

A few improvements are possible. `l` and `r` are not very helpful names. `l` seems like a left subtree, but it’s an element in the tree; `r` seems like a right subtree, but it’s a list of subtrees.

```
count (Leaf _value) = 0
count (Node _value subtrees) = 1 + sum (map count subtrees)
```

Now this works on a more complex example.

```
largerExample :: Tree Int
largerExample
  = Node 1      -- +1
    [ Node 2    -- +1
      [ Leaf 4  -- +0
      ]
    , Node 3    -- +1
      [ Leaf 5  -- +0
      , Leaf 6  -- +0
      ]
    ]
```

`count largerExample` is 3.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: You are trying to apply the `count` function to a value of `[Tree a]`. But it expects a value of `Tree a` (just a single tree, not a list of trees).

To make it compile you need to deal with the list somehow. You could use the `Data.List.foldl` function like this:

```hs
count :: Tree a -> Integer
count (Leaf a) = 0
count (Node l r) = 1 + count l + foldl (\i t -> i + count t) 0 r
```

Comment: `foldl` is an especially poor tool for this. Really, `foldl` is a poor tool for everything. `foldl'` would be okay, but I'd still suggest `sum (map count r)`. Also, `count l` is ill-typed, so that needs fixing too.